# None output in the assignments of lists

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,3]
x=a.append(2009)
print (x)
```

Output is :

```
None
```

What is the main reason of it ?

Comment: `append` returns None...

Comment: The reason is that `append` modifies the list in place and returns None.  Search to find gazillions of other questions about this on here.